# kotlin-maven-noarg not working if my kotlin app is built with Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, plugins, kotlin

When I build my app using Jenkins, kotlin-maven-noarg is not applied. It is applied when I build locally.

The only difference I found between my local build and my Jenkins build is the following lines (with -X option):

Local:

```
[DEBUG] Module name is my-module
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\maven\repository\org\jetbrains\kotlin\kotlin-maven-noarg\1.2.20\_maven.repositories
[DEBUG] Plugin classpaths are: C:\maven\repository\org\jetbrains\kotlin\kotlin-maven-noarg\1.2.20\kotlin-maven-noarg-1.2.20.jar
[DEBUG] Looking for plugin jpa
[DEBUG] Got plugin instancejpa of type org.jetbrains.kotlin.test.KotlinJpaMavenPluginExtension
[INFO] Applied plugin: 'jpa'
```

Jenkins:

```
[DEBUG] Module name is my-module
[DEBUG] Verifying availability of /data/jenkins/jenkins_home/maven-repositories/1/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-maven-noarg/1.2.20/kotlin-maven-noarg-1.2.20.jar from []
[DEBUG] Looking for plugin jpa
[DEBUG] Got plugin instancejpa of type org.jetbrains.kotlin.test.KotlinJpaMavenPluginExtension
[INFO] Applied plugin: 'jpa'
```

Same maven version, only the OS is different (local build on Windows and jenkins build on Linux).

Here is an extract of my pom.xml:

```xml
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <languageVersion>1.2</languageVersion>
            <compilerPlugins>
                <plugin>jpa</plugin>
            </compilerPlugins>
        </configuration>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>compile</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>test-compile</id>
                <phase>test-compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test-compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Any idea why my plugin is not applied on Jenkins?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tested your project against with maven `maven clean test` rather than IDE?

Comment: Yes I did, my "Local build" is a `mvn clean install -X` (same on Jenkins btw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue: my local maven was version 3.0.4 and Jenkins 3.0.3. An update to 3.0.4 on Jenkins fixed it.